# How to make a raw C++ pointer to point to a template class without specifying the type?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

I have seen this in a large codebase, in a header file. When I tried to do it in a source file the compiler complained. The fact that it was OK for the compiler for it being in the header file was still amusing, so I'd like to know how and why it was working. It was a very complex class so I couldn't decipher it.

So here is a simple class:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
 public:
  Container(T value) : _value(value){};
  T get() { return _value; }
  void set(T value) { _value = value; }

 private:
  T _value;
};
```

Now in some other header file, I have this other class:

```
class ContainerFactory
{
  private:
    Containter<int> *_container1{nullptr}; //this will work as expected
    Container *_container2{nullptr}; //this won't work, the compiler will ask for a type
    std::map<Container*, UIControl*> _map; //this won't work either, but it is handy
    //if I have several types of Container.
}
```

What so called "tricks" do I have to do in order for `_container2` declaration to compiler. I tried a forward declaration and it didn't work obviously. Should I make another class that derives from `Container` and do some additional stuff? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Class templates are not types; they are blueprints for creating types.  You cannot form a pointer to a `Container` because `Container` is not a type, and there can never be `Container` objects for it to point to.

Comment: The version in the header file could have been: never included; within another template which was never instantiated; or not quite as identical to the version in source as you thought

Comment: @MilesBudnek, I get what you're saying, but I have seen the code with my eyes. It was just a class that was implementing way too many interface, like some 5 of them, and it was a templated class itself, as far as I can recall. What I want is some skeletal code that accomplishes this.

Comment: @armanali: "*I get what you're saying, but I have seen the code with my eyes.*" Then prove it by showing the code you have seen with your own eyes. The code you posted here cannot compile, and the code as you have described it cannot compile *unless* it was in the `Container` template itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I would have if it was my code:)

Comment: OK, it is just the constructor that is templated actually. So this is a wrong example.

Comment: I am going to delete my question:)

Comment: @armanali Within the template itself you can refer to it by name alone e.g. `template <typename T> class Node { Node *next; }`, maybe that's what you saw.

Answer (score 2):

A template is a construct which generates C++ entities (classes, functions, and variables at present). But a template by itself is *not* the thing it generates; it's just a pattern for generating things. It's a fiction that exists at compile time, not a thing that lives in memory somewhere.

So you cannot have a pointer to a template, nor can you have an object of a template.

You can accomplish the broad idea of what you want, an object that could refer to any instantiation of some template. But this would involve creating a type-erased object which provides a specific interface for accessing the type-erased object.

However, type erasure is usually employed when the type you're trying to deal with cannot be named for various reasons or needs to be flexible. If your type is a concrete type, then it *must* have some idea of what data it stores; if it didn't, it wouldn't be able to use `get` or `set` (since those have to return a known type). So either your type needs to be a template (and thus the user defines which `Container<T>` it works with), or the nature of the type needs to define the `Container`'s template parameter.

Comment: So how would you modify the class `Container` to accomplish it? I want a very minimal example. Should `ContainerFactory` become templated as well?

Comment: @armanali: I can't provide any particular details because *you* haven't provided any particular details on what is actually going on. Why do you need this? What do you intend for it to do? How do you intend to use this object whose type is unknown to you? Etc.

Comment: the code was implementing a property descriptor, which is to define a property that can contain any type, be it int, double or an std::string, then based on those properties the UI gets created. Now the data portion of the UI contains a map with keys being that property descriptor and the value being the UI control that gets shown on the screen. Since the property can be of any type, which means of any specialization of the template, it's more convenient to have one map where everything can be stored.

Comment: I have modified my `ContainerFactory` class to make the use case more compelling.

Comment: well maybe it can be achieved through `std::variant` as well, but the code that I'm looking at does not use it... so I was just curious to see how it is achieving it. I am going to ask the person who has written it.